# Xcode: iAds in 5 ViewControllers: How?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, iad

Problem: I can't get one instance of iAds to be viewed in 5 viewcontrollers.

I used the iAdSuite example from dev.apple.com to integrate iAds into my app. All is fine until one uses the back button to go back a page within the NavControllerstack. The Ad doesnt reintegrate into the view.

One logical approach seemed to me to load up one instance of the adbannerview into my main window in my AppDelegate:

```
[self.window addSubview:MainView];    
[self.MainView addSubview:NavController.view];    
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

MainView takes the full window but is set to stretch up when the adbanner is loaded.

I seem to be doing something wrong because the navcontroller view seems to always take up the entire screen.

Question: How can I succesfully implement iAds in my rootview? (Or succesfully migrate iads around)

Comment: Understanding your view hierarchy will help you determine where to place it. I would write out on paper what view controller presents/owns what other ones and how they are visible etc. You'll probably see that the window level is where a main view controller or two originate from and that putting an iAd view here should make it included on every screen or so.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as stated in the question. I seem to now have been able to get the iads to show up in my main window. The problem is that when an iadaction starts, all other subviews are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Could you keep a global reference to the iAd Banner and call `[adBanner.view removeFromSuperView]` followed by `[theViewThatYouWantToDisplayAdOn addSubview:adBanner.view]`

Comment: I want multiple viewcontrollers because else when the app would load it would load a too large nib file. When kept separated the independent nib's will only load when needed.